# Android get datd from a table which is in a list

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashtable

I have a  `ArrayList<Hashtable<String, String>>`

this is the hash table.

```
Hashtable<String, String> table = new Hashtable<String, String>();
```

the list will contain many hash tables. I need to traverse the list and get the element at the first index of every hashtable. can this be done in one  line of code? I want to use one variable and not make it complicated by using many loops and variables. hope I am clear. plz help.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to iterate over the list, and in each iteration you have to get the element at the first index.
It's not quite clear to me what you mean with "element at the first index of a Hashtable", however, since the order of elements in a Hashtable  or HashMap is not guaranteed. It would make sense, though, if you were looking for the value mapped to a specific key.

```
int i = 0;
for ( HashMap<String,String> map : listOfMaps )
{
    array[ i ] = System.out.println(map.get( "name" ));
    i++;
}
```

or:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < listOfMaps.length; i++ )
{
    array[ i ] = map.get("name");
}
```

Comment: sorry for that. I will tel it clearly. I have list of hastables. I need to acess the value for the key "name " from every  hashtable in the list..

Comment: I have updated the pseudocode accordingly. What you have to do inside the loop, depends of course on what you want to do with the values mapped to "name" - probably store them in a data structure for further processing elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am able to get the values. But how do I store the values in a array after each itireation. array[?] = map.get(key) . what should come in the place of the question mark(array[?]).

Comment: I have edited the sample code a bit more. The rest I leave to you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried both. I amgeting nullPOinterException